# Polygon Perimeter from Raster with Conditions

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap

How can a polygon be created around a group of raster cells in ArcMap?

Specifically, given the set of red cells in the figure, I'd like to create a polygon that represents the perimeter. The criteria is that the perimeter excludes cells which are disconnected from the main red area by one or two white cells. I do want to avoid coding in ArcMap.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the Region Group command; it will identify unique IDs for each disconnected zone. From here, depending on the criteria you're using to define the main zone, you can use Raster Calculator with to keep the zones of interest. As an example:

```
Con(ZonalGeometry(RegionGroup(YourRas, "FOUR"), "VALUE", "AREA") == Max(ZonalGeometry(RegionGroup(YourRas, "FOUR"), "VALUE", "AREA")), 1)
```

Would identify the largest contiguous zone, which you could then vectorize with "Raster to Polygon".

Alternatively, if you really want zero coding, just use "Raster to Polygon", output your polygons to a geodatabase, sort by the Shape_Area field and keep the largest.